# Matrix equation not properly updating in time

Tags: matrix, fortran, matrix-multiplication

As a simple example to illustrate my point, I am trying to solve the following equation `f(t+1) = f(t) + f(t)*Tr (f^2)` starting at t=0 where Tr is the trace of a matrix (sum of diagonal elements).  Below I provide a basic code.  My code compiles with no errors but is not updating the solution as I want.  My expected result is also below which I calculated by hand (it's very easy to check by hand via matrix multiplication).

In my sample code below I have two variables that store solution, `g` is for `f(t=0)` which I implement, and then I store `f(t+1)` as `f`.

```
complex,dimension(3,3) :: f,g
integer :: k,l,m,p,q
```

Assume g=f(t=0) is defined as below

```
do l=1,3 !matrix index loops
  do k=1,3 !matrix index loops

        if (k == l) then

            g(k,l) = cmplx(0.2,0)

        else if ( k /= l) then

            g(k,l) = cmplx(0,0)

        end if


  end do 
end do
```

I have checked this result is indeed what I want it to be, so I know f at t=0 is defined properly.

Now I try to use this matrix at t=0 and find the matrix for all time, governed by the equation `f(t+1) = f(t)+f(t)*Tr(f^2)`, but this is where I am not correctly implementing the code I want.

```
do m=1,3 !loop for 3 time iterations

       do p=1,3 !loops for dummy indices for matrix trace
         do q=1,3 

               g(1,1) = g(1,1) + g(1,1)*g(p,q)*g(p,q) !compute trace here
               f(1,1) = g(1,1)  

               !f(2,2) = g(2,2) + g(2,2)*g(p,q)*g(p,q)
               !f(3,3) = g(3,3) + g(3,3)*g(p,q)*g(p,q)

               !assume all other matrix elements are zero except diagonal


    end do
  end do   

end do
```

Printing this result is done by

```
print*, "calculated f where m=", m
do k=1,3
   print*, (f(k,l), l=1,3) 
end do
```

This is when I realize my code is not being implemented correctly.
When I print `f(k,l)` I expect for t=1 a result of `0.224*identity matrix` and now I get this.  However for t=2 the output is not right. So my code is being updated correctly for the first time iteration, but not after that.

I am looking for a solution as to how to properly implement the equation I want to obtain the result I am expecting.

Comment: I'm confused about several things. What is `f(k,l,i,j)` you reference in the second-to-last paragraph? Where are you actually computing the trace? What is the point of looping over `f(1,1) = g(1,1) + g(1,1)*g(p,q)*g(p,q)` if you're overwriting `f(1,1)` every time - won't the final answer just have `f(1,1)=g(1,1)+g(1,1)*g(3,3)*g(3,3)`?

Comment: @Ross Sorry I copy pasted my actual code which uses 4D arrays hence the indices i,j; forget those for this simple example.  Thanks for catching that.  You're definitely right, but that is why I am stuck.  I'm not entirely sure what the final answer would be I did try figuring out what fortran was doing but I couldn't.  I realize my algorithm isn't being implemented right.  I want to properly update the solution, for ex: I want to update f(1,1), f(2,2), f(3,3) for each time step according to the equation f(t+1) = f(t)+f(t)*Tr(f^2).

Lastly, I compute the trace here : g(p,q)*g(p,q)

Comment: Try computing each component more carefully. For example, compute `f^2` and store it. Then compute the trace of *that*, and store it. Then compute the update.

Comment: @Ross ok I am going to try that and update my post. However, how do I actually compute the update? I want to do this for many many time iterations. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Ross Okay I did that and updated the post.  My equation actually works for the first time iteration now; t=0,t=1.  However, it  fails for the second iteration .  I am just working with the first entry in the matrix , f(1,1) and I see at t=0 f(1,1) is correct, and at t=1 f(1,1) is correct but at t=2, f(1,1) is not correct and for all later times it is not right.  How can I properly update f(1,1) for later times (all time)?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer a couple things you seem to be having trouble with. First, the trace. The trace of a 3x3 matrix is `A(1,1)+A(2,2)+A(3,3)`. The first and second indexes are the same, so we use *one* loop variable. To compute the trace of an `NxN` matrix `A`:

```
trace = 0.
do i=1,N
   trace = trace + A(i,i)
enddo
```

I *think* you're trying to loop over `p` and `q` to compute your trace which is incorrect. In that sum, you'll add in terms like `A(2,3)` which is wrong.

Second, to compute the update, I recommend you compute the updated `f` into `fNew`, and then your code would look something like:

```
do m=1,3   ! time
   ! -- Compute f^2 (with loops not shown)
   f2 = ...

   ! -- Compute trace of f2 (with loop not shown)
   trace = ...

   ! -- Compute new f
   do j=1,3
      do i=1,3
         fNew(i,j) = f(i,j) + trace*f(i,j)
      enddo
   enddo

   ! -- Now update f, perhaps recording fNew-f for some residual
   ! -- The LHS and RHS are both arrays of dimension (3,3),
   ! -- so fortran will automatically perform an array operation
   f = fNew
enddo
```

This method has two advantages. First, your code actually looks like the math you're trying to do, and is easy to follow. This is *very* important for realistic problesm which are not so simple. Second, if `fNew(i,j)` depended on `f(i+1,j)`, for example, you are not updating to the next time level while the current time level values still need to be used.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think this all makes a lot of sense to me, I may have some questions if so I will comment  tomorrow as it is very late by me now

Comment: I have two questions for you. 1st one is:  when you update the solution f using f=fNew, how come you dont need to update the solution for all i,j via putting f=fNew under do loops?  What I mean is, how come we don't need to use:
do i=1,3
do j=1,3
f(i,j) = fNew(i,j)
end do
end do.

My 2nd question is: Is it computationally better if I first loop over j and second loop over i?  In your code you loop over i first, then j.  However the matrix has indices, f(i,j); so is it more efficient to loop over the second index first? (In this case it would be j, not i).   Thanks so much!

Comment: @Integrals You're right about the loop order, although at this stage I think it's best to ignore optimizations such as those. I've edited the question anyways. Setting `f=fNew` is an array operation, fortran will automatically do the operation for each element of `f` and `fNew` because they're the same shape.

Comment: yes I learned about the loop order on here but don't deeply understand it still. Thanks for your clear solution. I didn't know that it was an array operation, I always used do loops to do these kinds of things. Glad I know now.